# Javascript, is using the var keyword a best practice?

Tags: javascript

It seems to me that anytime a variable is declared, it should use the var keyword (unless it's specifically trying to access a global variable). Particularly because local variables can be collected when their function exits. But does it make any difference in something like a for loop?

`for(var i = 0; i < ...; i++)`

Generally, is there any standard best practice about the use of var keyword?

Comment: Yes, it's good practice to use the `var` keyword, always! Not doing so creates a global, which one generally doesn't want to do, and that applies to inside a `for` statement as well.

Comment: Always declare variables with `var`. Use "strict" mode by including the line `"use strict";` at the top of your script blocks and/or namespace wrapper functions to catch inadvertent assignments without `var` (and typos etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Generally, is there any standard best practice about the use of var keyword?

Yes there is. And that is to use `var` ***every time***.

> But does it make any difference in something like a for loop?

There is no block-scope in javascript *yet*. So it makes no difference whatsoever. It is same as

```
var i; 
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // you can access i inside
}  // as well as outside the loop
```

Declaring variables without `var` keyword throws an error when used in `'use strict'`. So it's always better to use `var` keyword and avoid the ambiguity by attaching a property to `window` if you want it to be global.

Ah forgot about `let` keyword, which will make its way in ES6, which allows for a block scope. So it can be written as

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   // i can be accessed here but not outside this block
}
```

Also it's worth noting is that

> [**MDN:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) First, strict mode makes it impossible to accidentally create global
>   variables. In normal JavaScript mistyping a variable in an assignment
>   creates a new property on the global object and continues to "work"
>   **(although future failure is possible: likely, in *modern JavaScript*)**

which means, that it is *considered* an *accidental mistake* if you omit `var` keyword and omitting it might not work in the future iterations of ECMAScript aka Javascript.

Use `var` and you'll not pollute global context, your variables will be context-aware and be fail-proof for future versions of javascript, or in MDN's words, **modern JavaScript**.

Comment: "There is no block-scope in javascript" - not true for ES6! :) Don't forget about [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Comment: @brianvaughn I didn't add it as it was not yet available, thanks though for pointing. Edited to include it.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, the `var` keyword **appears** to be optional. This is incorrect.

With `var`, a variable is created in the current scope. Without it, the variable is attached to the global scope. (This is `window` in the browser).

You should absolutely use `var` wherever possible. If you mean to intentionally attach a variable to the window, state that directly:

```
window.foobar = 'some text';
```

Declaring a variable in a for-loop is the same as declaring a variable anywhere else.

I doubt you want every loop in your program all trying to use `window.i` the same time, which is what will happen if you don't use `var`.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are partially wrong.

Only functions have scope in javascript, so a for loop `var` has no actual functional difference. Using `var` in for loops does create the semantic implication that the value shouldn't be used later, though.

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){}console.log(i);
for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++){}console.log(j);
q = 17
for(var q = 0; q < 5; q++){}console.log(q);
```

All 3 output `5` but with a `var` declaration I would not expect a future user of the for loop variable.